# Select query with MySql left join

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 3 table (property, facility, property_facility)

Now I want to get all facilities from `facility` table alone with property data to given property ID.

I tried it with `LEFT JOIN` as below. But I cannot get all facilities from facility table.

```
SELECT property_id
     , contract_id
     , type_id
     , location_id
     , beds
     , ROUND(price,3) as price
     , f.facility_id
     , f.name
     , pf.facility_id
FROM  facility f  
LEFT JOIN property_facility pf ON pf.facility_id = f.facility_id AND pf.property_id = 6
LEFT JOIN property p USING(property_id) 
WHERE p.property_id = 6
```

Can anybody tell me how I make this query correctly?

Comment: this is because you join also on property_id = 6.

Comment: yes, if you remove "AND pf.property_id = 6" it should work

Comment: Move that p.property_id = 6 from WHERE to the ON clause.

Comment: @jarlh Do I need to remove `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it'd be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is filtering out the facilities that do not match.  You will need to switch the `USING` to `ON` and do:

```
FROM facility f LEFT JOIN
     property_facility pf
     ON pf.facility_id = f.facility_id AND
        pf.property_id = 6 LEFT JOIN
     property p 
     ON p.property_id = pf.property_id AND p.property_id = 6
```

You seem to understand the concept, because you are using the same condition for the first `JOIN`.

Well, actually, the `property_id` doesn't change.  So, you can just remove the `WHERE` clause and continue with `USING` if you prefer.